# Convert serial port raw data buffer into a array of numbers?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I installed [serialport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) module.

In this function:

```
port.on('data', function (data) {.....});
```

`data`(the argument of the callback) holds the raw data being received on the serial port. I know `data` is buffer.

How to convert the buffer into an array of numbers(8bit)?

Comment: You could have search before asking... [Buffer doc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you'll receive a buffer. So you should be able to get it from

```
s = data.toString('hex');
ss = s.match(/.{1,2}/g);
numbers = ss.map(function (x) {return parseInt(x, 16);});
```

Comment: Something like that but that doesn't exhaust the question. When I use that function I get something like this `2aaff56ca5`. How to take the first byte `2a` which is 42(dec) and use it as a number?

Comment: Ok, sorry, overlooked that. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Logging the hex as a string:

```
port.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('> ', data.toString('utf-8'))
})
```

Comment: I don't think converting the data to a string was what they were asking for. They said they wanted it as numbers.